# zeep Client() call returns Error: The namespace defined on the xsd:import doesn't match the imported targetNamespace located at:

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

We have a need to call SOAP web services using zeep python package.  While starting to work on this project I have implemented a few web services calls and they worked as advertised.  However, one of the web services is not working well with zeep.  The call to read WSDL:

```
client = Client('http://***/Products.asmx?WSDL', settings=settings)
```

returns:

zeep.exceptions.XMLParseError: The namespace defined on the xsd:import doesn't match the imported targetNamespace located at 'http://***/Products.asmx?WSDL'  (http://**/Products.asmx?WSDL:1475)

settings are set to

```
strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True
```

zeep version is 3.3.0

Question: what could cause such an error?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with python 3.6 and zeep 3.3.0. Code used to work in zeep 3.2. Fix itself when I upgraded to 3.3.1. Try upgrade zeep to 3.3.1.

Comment: Awesome!  Heneff, thank you very much for your response.  The upgrade to 3.3.1 from 3.3.0 has resolved this issue.